# Get data in parts from database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, data-paging

I need get all records from table with Take = 1000 and skip all taken records. How should I implement?

```
var result = context.MyDB.Where(x=>x.ID = ID).Take(1000);
```

Comment: What is a taked record? Can you please consider we are not in your brain? In a normal select you never have to skip anything - that isa business need and you have to sort of - ah - as a complete question here.

Comment: Are you saying you want to get all the records from the table, but 1000 records at a time?

Comment: Simon Clough, yes, I want get all records by 1000 records at time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take all the records from the db, 1000 at a time, something like this should do the job then.

```
var startRecord = 0;
var records = db.where(x=>x.ID ==ID).Skip(startRecord).Take(1000);
while (records.Any())
{
  startRecord += 1000;
  // do something with your records

  records = db.where(x=>x.ID ==ID).Skip(startRecord).Take(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you need to skip taken records before so

```
var result = context.MyDB.Where(x=>x.ID =ID).Skip(20000).Take(1000);
```

20000 can be your (pageNumber -1) * pagesize

Comment: What if in this table we have only 1000 records.